# how to disable submit button using javascript

Tags: javascript, html

i am trying to disable if the input is not up to certain numbers of later, where the input class =viewbox,  and the button =btn-next
i have tried to make it up but it's not working, any working solution will be so much appreciated.

```
let viewBox = document.querySelector(".viewbox");
let btnNext = document.querySelector(".btn-next");

btnNext.disabled = true; 
viewBox.addEventListener("change", stateHandle);

function stateHandle() {
    if (document.querySelector(".viewbox").value === "5") {
      btnNext.disabled = true; 
    } else {
      btnNext.disabled = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm trying to follow what you want to do. Could you please explain more clearly what you want the function of your code to be?

Comment: `if (document.querySelector(".viewbox").value.length < 5)`, maybe? Though, I didn't understand your question well, but if you're trying to disable the Next button if the number of letters in the input is less than 5?

Comment: Your question is not clear.  Because code in your question is not a [mre] the reader has to make assumptions about what you're doing that could easily be incorrect.  Please include your HTML at the least.

Comment: `viewBox.addEventListener("input", function() { btnNext.disabled =  this.value.length <5 })` or if the number 5: `viewBox.addEventListener("input", function() { btnNext.disabled = +this.value <5 })`

Comment: i was trying say that if input is less than or 5 characters, the button should be disabled

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change the event listner from `change` to `input` as change will not show the realtime changes, below is the working code for your problem,

I have changed the input colors for your better understanding.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h1 style="background-color: red;">Hello World!</h1>
<p>This is a paragraph.</p>
<input type="text" placeholder="view port" class="viewbox"/>
<input type="button" placeholder="btn next" class="btn-next"/>

<script>

let viewBox = document.querySelector(".viewbox");
let btnNext = document.querySelector(".btn-next");

btnNext.disabled = true; 
viewBox.addEventListener("input", ()=>stateHandle());

function stateHandle() {
    if (document.querySelector(".viewbox").value.length <= 5) {
      btnNext.style.backgroundColor = "blue"; 
      btnNext.disabled = true; 
    } else {
      btnNext.style.background = "red";
      btnNext.disabled = false;
    }
}

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: bro the code is working but not wot working in my work i don't know where the fault is

Comment: <form action="index.php" method="post">
       <div class="key-box">
          <p class="caution">
          </p>
            <label for=""></label>
           <input type="text" class="viewbox"  placeholder="Enter your secret recovery phrase" required/>
           <p class="ending"></p>
           <button value="submit" class="btn-next">Verify</button>
        </div>   
    </form>